# Microsoft Access 2010 query yields no results

Tags: ms-access, zipcode

I am trying to scale down a data set by zip code (which is one of my fields) through a query.  I have tried using a the critera syntax for range and also for inclusive zip codes.  Example:

```
Range:
<=05301 AND 05363=> 

Inclusive:
<05301, 05302, 05303, 05304, 05360, 05361, 05362, OR 05363>
```

Each of these (which I found on instructional websites) yields no results, despite each of those zip codes being present in my data set.  What can I do to have my list of addresses be sorted by this range of zip codes, and have my results show up?

Comment: Please show your actual query.  If you are showing what you put in the query designer it would be either: Between '05301' and '05363' or >= '05301' AND <= '05363'

Answer (score 2):

If your zip codes begin with a 0 I'm guessing they are not a numeric type but instead a text? If so try the condition:

[Zip Code] in ('05301','05302','05303','05304','05360','05361','05362','05363')

Also, check for leading spaces in your data if they are text with Trim([Zip Code])